# ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll and IScrollInfo in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

There is **IScrollInfo** interface, but there's no **ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll** property. Does it mean that there is no way to use element with custom **IScrollInfo** implementation in Silverlight?

Comment: Its difficult to understand what it is you are actually asking.  Neither `IScrollInfo` nor `ScrollViewer` have a `CanContentScroll` so where do you get that from?

Comment: ScrollViewer in WPF does have CanContentScroll property, which tells that content knows how to scroll itself, i.e. it implements IScrollInfo.